# SVG coordinate conversions

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am using SnapSVG to display a pretty complex image.  Part of the image is a circle that I would like to rotate when the user does a click/drag.

I've been reading all evening about coordinate systems and it just isn't clicking.   I read [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh535760(v=vs.85).aspx) and tried to adapt the code to convert the screen location of the click to my SVG coordinates.

Here is the code I'm trying...

```
function dragStart(x, y, event) {
    var inverse = event.srcElement.getScreenCTM().inverse();
    var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = event.clientX;
    point.y = event.clientY;
    var final = point.matrixTransform(inverse);
    console.log('Before: (' + point.x + ', ' + point.y + ')');
    console.log('Final: (' + final.x + ', ' + final.y + ')');
}
```

The odd thing is that the X value is returning exactly what I would expect.  But the Y value makes no sense at all.

EDIT:  Fiddle added [here](https://jsfiddle.net/larrynator/v004ftc8/)

I've stripped the SVG down to the bare minimum.  The black outer ring is static.  The white inner ring will rotate when the user clicks and drags.  The SVG was created so that the center of the ring is at (0,0) and the SVG has a width and height of 600.  Open your browser's developer tools console and click on the image.  As you can see, when you click close to the center of the red circle the x coordinate is near zero as expected.  But the Y value is way off.

Comment: Please post the SVG code displaying the image.

Comment: As Arif says, I would put a minimal testing example on a jsfiddle or similar. Its unusual to need to go to that length in Snap as it provides x,y inside its handler, so not sure why you need to do any of what you are currently doing without more information or a jsfiddle.